# max(list) vs comparing each element with max(ele1,ele2) in list iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, arraylist, time-complexity

let's say I have a list which is `arr = [1,6,0,9,3,12,8,5]`, in order to get the maximum integer from the list, I can use the following two methods:

1.)

```
x = max(arr)
```

2.)

```
x = 0
for ele in arr:
    x = max(x,ele)
```

now I wonder, what's the performance of each method ? and which one is faster ? and what are the time and space complexity ? which one is preferred ?

would the extra `max(x, ele)` comparisons in each iteration cost more time complexity than `max(arr)` ? or vice versa ?

==========================================

edited 8/26/23
now everyone says first one is faster, how about in the example below ?

given a list `arr = [1,6,0,9,3,12,8,5]`, I wanna make a new list from all elements inside arr that the elements can divide by 3, and keep track of the max element in it.

1.)

```
newArr = []
for ele in arr:
    if ele%3 == 0:
        newArr.append(ele)
x = max(newArr) #now newArr should be [6,0,9,3,12]
```

2.)

```
newArr = []
x = 0
for ele in arr:
    if ele%3 == 0:
        newArr.append(ele)
        if ele > x:   #would x = max(x, ele) cause more time complexity ?
            x = ele
```

now in this example, would the 2nd approach have less time complexity because it only iterate once for both appending & comparing? And would the 1st approach have more time complexity because of the max(newArr) which is O(n) more ?

I did the test like @KellyBundy did, seems like `if ele > x: x = ele` is way faster than `x = max(x, ele)`, and little bit faster than `max(newArr)`, see result below.

https://perfpy.com/433

another test was also done with nested list, and max(arr) is much faster this time

https://perfpy.com/436

but when I did it with another compiler, the results don't differ that much, very interesting, below are the codes that I compiled using programiz's online compiler

https://dpaste.org/UPFWB

Comment: `max()` is implemented in optimized C code, your loop uses the Python interpreter, so it will be slower.

Comment: Both are O(n), but the cost of each iteration is much more in version 2.

Comment: Option 2 has a lot of variable references which all turn into getting and settting items in the global dict. Intermediate variables in `max` are anonymous (and in C) so faster.

Comment: BTW, your version will give the wrong answer if there are any negative numbers in the list.

Comment: In your 2nd version, `max` is getting called `n` times, so the extra cost comes in your 2nd version because of this.

Comment: @Barmar *"your loop uses the Python interpreter, so it will be slower"* - If I replace their loop body with `if ele > x: x = ele`, then with that argument of yours, it should still be slower, but in my testing, it's *faster*.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's very surprising.

Comment: @KellyBundy I just tried it at perfpy.com, your version is about half as fast as `max(arr)` with a 10K list. https://perfpy.com/429

Comment: @Barmar Maybe because that's Python 3.8? I used 3.11 (and longer lists). See benchmark in my answer now.

Comment: @KellyBundy just edited the question, please see the additional example

Comment: @Barmar how about the new added example ?

Comment: "runtime complexity" is a theoretical construct which tells you something about the asymptotic runtime of the algorithm when the size of the problem goes to infinitiy.  With respect to  "runtime complexity" both approaches are equal, ie *O(n)*. If you want to know which approach is faster in a certain sitaution, you probably have to do a benchmark ...

Comment: As a side remark, the self written code does not solve the task. Consider `arr = [-1]`.

Comment: For such a computation, Numpy should be MUCH faster and use far less RAM. One reason is that Numpy is written in C, and another reason is that is makes use of SIMD instructions.

Comment: @Aziuth As written, the code only works correctly when the list contains non-negative numbers. It's trivially fixed by initializing `x = arr[0]`; this has negligible impact on the performance issue.

Comment: *"but when I did it with another compiler, the results don't differ that much, very interesting"* - Not interesting at all and easily explained (but I don't participate in chameleon questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Times for 100000 elements (random, increasing or decreasing) with your two ways and one without using `max` at all:

```
random
  1.79 ± 0.02 ms  selfmade
  2.04 ± 0.02 ms  just_max
 17.62 ± 0.50 ms  repeated_max

increasing
  1.89 ± 0.01 ms  selfmade
  2.09 ± 0.04 ms  just_max
 17.23 ± 0.09 ms  repeated_max

decreasing
  1.76 ± 0.04 ms  selfmade
  2.06 ± 0.03 ms  just_max
 18.11 ± 0.46 ms  repeated_max

Python: 3.11.4 (main, Jun 24 2023, 10:18:04) [GCC 13.1.1 20230429]
```

Benchmark code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVNLjtQwEF2w8ylql6SViaYHGkGk5gzsoyhyd8ozZmInsp1RWq05CZvZwJ4jwDE4DRXb6Q8aFmQVV9V7fu_Z_vp9OLiHXr-8fBuduPnw-83PFgV8Ga1rFJ9SbkxWMqBvgi0sFV8w6EajYWJsRhgckDtsX0Hd-j_RG8AOQWqgduhe8k45dV9jttgJxVv8L1YpfPkTTOfagqTGX9swMeq9pdbiO7_yk580MCbV0BsHhuu2V0yYXoGTCqWD2Amr0LGOO2mdJO7YVcg10bkWnxYqe7DBqEPr0o7vsMvh7HUwUsdySGfeYNZ6FCVUtU9AzP69h2c_4mOjvW0qsrN_N6MqBytY41uPczPOkghsU09biTqryk1dn0AxJJEcZ-mps1n5vrgTz_DrBxy9D19752vKQsJO59LM7BTUPaZ3mwsd14qvz8eRxJAgWVa7lpcg_MHnoEe1Q7NdZ9eAKLvgw4CabGRnAeLCnt8rh0c8bH0yF3pCwkteOYiiaTRX2DSRKwzQQpO69e1qtWH-rJJwC5I8Xodi_9DLPdo0mJ4nPxLf41ZnWURIvTfIrdT3hOrobsRZmlhGWvzXSFWWN-uaBllQlHz2b7ekObpExRMaK3udhZccH_TysP8A)):

```py
def just_max(arr):
    x = max(arr)
    return x

def repeated_max(arr):
    x = 0
    for ele in arr:
        x = max(x,ele)
    return x

def selfmade(arr):
    x = 0
    for ele in arr:
        if ele > x:
            x = ele
    return x


funcs = just_max, repeated_max, selfmade

import random
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
import sys

def test(label, arr):
    print(label)
    times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
    def stats(f):
        ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
        return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} ms '

    for _ in range(25):
        for f in funcs:
            t = timeit(lambda: f(arr), number=1)
            times[f].append(t)

    for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
        print(stats(f), f.__name__)

    print()

n = 10**5
test('random', random.choices(range(10**9), k=n))
test('increasing', list(range(n)))
test('decreasing', list(range(n)[::-1]))

print('Python:', sys.version)
```

Comment: I ran your code on my MacBook M1, and `just_max` is the winner in all 3 cases. And only `selfmade` shows a significant difference in speed between the cases.

Comment: I'm running Python 3.11.

Comment: @Barmar Can you show the results (I guess it'd be readable in a comment, or put it on dpaste.org or so)? I'm not familiar with Macs. About M1 I've only heard problems or differing speeds. Maybe the CPU makes the difference, or maybe different compiler optimization settings...

Comment: https://dpaste.org/mzLOj

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. Nice fast&stable results :-). Anyway, at least it agrees that `repeated_max` is **much** slower, and that's what the question is about. I'm surprised myself that `selfmade` is fastest for me, I also checked the [max() source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d2340ef25721b6a72d45d4508c672c4be38c67d3/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1859) and don't see anything obvious that could explain its slowness...

Comment: @KellyBundy I think `selfmade` doesn't need to pass the 2 variables to the max() function, so they just do the comparison in-place ? and if `max(x, ele)` is used, would it cost O(2) more ?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of time complexity, both methods have the same linear time complexity `O(n)`. However, the first method `(max(arr))`might have a slight advantage in terms of performance, as it uses a single function optimized for this task, whereas the second method involves a loop with multiple comparisons in each iteration. The actual performance difference might be negligible for small lists, but for larger lists, the first method might be slightly faster due to its optimized nature.

so, you should prefer using the built-in `max(arr)` function, as it's designed for this specific purpose and is likely to be well-optimized.

Comment: how about in the new added example i just addded ?